# Debugging a sigtrap in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, random

In a recent program I've made I had some worrying random crashes/ crash on shutdown, after stripping down I think I've narrowed it down to a SIGTRAP which happens when a vector is created under specific circumstances. The main bulk of the code can be found here :http://pastebin.com/xp9Cm04Q and the tile class here : http://pastebin.com/Niv7SSyF (the issue arises when the buildworld subroutine is ran) and the console output can be found here http://pastebin.com/7HyaMke8 . The debugger goes to new_allicator when this happens, if that's worth knowing.

Also note that for some reason removing the calls to rTest in the tiles (which only makes a call to the RNG that class has), but only if another subZone has been created since then. Needless to say I am completely baffled as to why this is happening.

Am I doing anything dumb here? I'm only using std libraries, so I don't think I could of installed them wrong or anything. Is this an issue I can/should ignore? Any kind of help on how to approach this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you defined subZone and Tile copy constructors?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll try adding them and see if it changes anything.

Comment: After making a simply copy constructor that just copies over all the values in the class (not sure if this is just the same as the default) the error persists. To my knowledge I'm not using any funky memory management, hence why I didn't bother with making a copy constructor. Should I of made one anyway?

Comment: `tiles.back().back().giveRGen(&zoneRGen);`

Answer (score 0):

`tiles.back().back().giveRGen(&zoneRGen);`

One problem: your tile have a link to RNG object; that link would be broken then `subZone` copied. For example here:

`allZones.push_back( subZone( x , y , worldRGen() ) );`